# Testing apps made of electron application framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, electron, spectron

I am new to JS and electron in general, always been a back end dev using languages such as java and C#, I briefly worked on an older Perl project as well.

I have been tasked to create tests for one of our newer apps made in electron, I know that it is a JS program using a chromium core, and there is a testing framework for it called spectron. When I checkout the documentation, it seems to tell me that I can only use JavaScript bindings that it provided to test electron with selenium. My question is, is there a way I can use selenium webdriver with C# to test an electron app instead of using JavaScript? Do I have a choice here?

Comment: Yes you can use the Selenium C# client to drive electron. However it's preferable to write the tests in the same language as the application for the sake of maintainability.

Comment: Thanks, can you point to me a guide or step on how to use Selenium C# to test electron? Most guide that I can find are using sepctron and js to test electron.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md

Comment: Ok I will try to follow the guide and see if I can hook up Selenium